# How to manually increment the chapter number in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, context, context-mkiv

I need to manually adjust the chapter number in a book, so that three chapter numbers are missing.

```
\starttext
    \chapter{Birds of Africa}
    \chapter{Birds of Australia}
\stoptext
```

"Birds of Africa" should appear as chapter 1, but "Birds of Australia" should appear as chapter 5.

I tried `\incrementnumber[chapter][4]`, but this did not work.

How can I manually increment the chapter number?

Comment: This solution does not appear to work. Using ConTeXt 2013.06.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section heads do not have a number associated with them. You can try one of the following.

1. Use `ownnumber` (but this does not change the number of subsequent chapters)

   ```
   \setuphead[chapter][page=no] % so that the result is in one page
   \starttext
   \startchapter[title=Birds of Africa]
     Content
   \stopchapter
   \startchapter[title=Birds of Australia, ownnumber=5]
     Content
   \stopchapter
   \startchapter[title=Birds of Asia]
     Content
   \stopchapter
   \stoptext
   ```

   [image]
2. The second option is to define your own conversion that will also increment the chapter numbers of subsequent chapters.

   ```
   \setuphead[chapter][page=no] % so that the result is in one page

   \startluacode
     userdata = userdata or {}
     userdata.myconversion = function(n)
         if n >= 2 then
           context(n+3)
         else
           context(n)
         end
     end
   \stopluacode

   \define[1]\myconversion{\usercode{myconversion(#1)}}

   \defineconversion[myconversion][\myconversion]
   \setuphead[chapter][conversion=myconversion]
   \starttext
   \startchapter[title=Birds of Africa]
     Content
   \stopchapter
   \startchapter[title=Birds of Australia]
     Content
   \stopchapter
   \startchapter[title=Birds of Asia]
     Content
   \stopchapter
   \stoptext
   ```

   [image]